# issue in blackberry app with ksoap library

Tags: web-services, blackberry, java-me, ksoap2

I need to consume a web service from blackberry.

But i couldn't run the app with the Ksoap library - i am using ksoap2-j2me-core-2.1.2.jar.

when i run the app i got this run time issue

> org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope: Error!: Missing stack map in: org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.(int) at label: 30

And I have tried a preverified jar also - when running the app with a preverified jar, I got this issue ([refer to this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566341/issue-for-blackberry-webservice-consume))

Please suggest a solution, or another ksoap library for consuming web services using blackberry.

Comment: [You should use the preverified jar.](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Ksoap2-building-error/td-p/289601)  That should solve the `missing stack map` problem.  You have not given us enough information in your other question to solve the problem.  (Those warnings are not what's causing your web service client to fail.)

Comment: Thank you nate now i could consume my webservice...

Answer (score 0):

Include Source code of Ksoap in your source code

Comment: i have tried to include source code on my app but i have the same error for above link